# Editing Bootstrap them SASS as a newbie

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm an old school CSS editor. As a designer I look at the UI and make changes in Chrome and then write them to the CSS file.

This has worked perfectly well until this week :)

I am working on a Bootstrap theme and struggling to understand how you work back upwards through the rendered CSS to the variables.

Is there a simple and usable beginner approach to this way of working?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow ,please kindly refer this link,https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you can  learn how to ask good question

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but could you not use something like this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805

Comment: This looks super helpful. My old school designer brain is suffering from working backwards into a more code like environment. Thanks :)